# how to remove or disable a hyperlink from a iframe

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to remove or disable a hyperlink which is been present in a iframe.

Let's say i have a countdown time which has a watermark in a iframe and there is a javascrip version of it as well.

Any chance with a javascript to disable is.. I am placing this iframe in a Sharepoint 2010

Any help would be really helpful for me.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/ You didn't share any code with us, but I guess you could use JavaScript to find the element you need in DOM and then manipulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place some JavaScript in the iframe that grabs the element by ID. If you don't know the ID, grab all controls, loop through them until you find the control using some other property, e.g. the title of the hyperlink or text contained in the hyperlink. Once you have the control you can disable or hide it using JavaScript. E.g.

```
 <script>
function hide(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.style.display=elem.style.display=="none"?"block":"none";
  return false; 
}
</script>
```